# Crystal Report How to convert number to text (word by word)

Tags: crystal-reports

Just a quick question as I cant find it anywhere in google or in this forum,
Can we spell number word by word in Crystal Report? Please refer to the example below:

Using ToWords function, $1257 is spelled as One Thousand Two Hundred and Fifty Seven. I wanted to get ONE TWO FIVE SEVEN (so it is spelled word by word).

Thank you in advance. Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToWords` function to achieve this.

More help here

[image]

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------

Assuming you placed data in details section:

Create a formula `Initialze`

Shared Stringvar x:=" ";

Place this formula at the starting of the detail section

Create one more formula `display` to display the data as required.

```
Numbervar i;
Shared Stringvar x;
Stringvar array a:=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];


//if database field is integer then convert to string, but by seeing your data database field seems to be string
for i:=1 to length(Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)) do
(
IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[1] Then
(
x:=x+"ONE"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[2] Then
(
x:=x+"TWO"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[3] Then
(
x:=x+"THREE"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[4] Then
(
x:=x+"FOUR"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[5] Then
(
x:=x+"FIVE"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[6] Then
(
x:=x+"SIX"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[7] Then
(
x:=x+"SEVEN"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[8] Then
(
x:=x+"EIGHT"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[9] Then
(
x:=x+"NINE"+" "
)
Else IF Right(databasefield,Length("databasefield")-1)[i] = a[10] Then
(
x:=x+"ZERO"+" "
)

);
x;
```

Tested solution, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Siva,

Thanks for that. I think I phrase my question incorrectly. I have used ToWords before and it generates One Thousand Two Hundred and Fifty Seven. I was after ONE TWO FIVE SEVEN instead of having the thousands or hundreds. Thanks for the help!! Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Comment: Yes it is possible, will post solution in some time